# SSH "Connection reset by peer" error

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm was messing around on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. After installing postfix and opening ports 110 & 25 I reboot the instance. Now when I try and login via ssh I get this error:

```
Read from remote host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Connection reset by peer
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
```

Maybe this will help? I can't make heads or tails of it...

```
#ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/S2.pem ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

    OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/me/.ssh/config
    debug1: Applying options for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    debug1: Applying options for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem.
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem type -1
    debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem.
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem type -1
    debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem.
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
    debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
    debug3: key_read: missing keytype
    debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem type -1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH*
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 127/256
    debug2: bits set: 523/1024
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts
    debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 9
    debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:9
    debug2: bits set: 507/1024
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug2: kex_derive_keys
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem (0x0)
    debug2: key: /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem (0x0)
    debug2: key: /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem (0x0)
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
    debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/S2.pem
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
    debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
    debug2: channel 0: send open
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
    debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
      #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cfd -1)

    debug3: channel 0: close_fds r 4 w 5 e 6 c -1
    Read from remote host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Connection reset by peer
    Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
    Transferred: sent 1776, received 1792 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
    Bytes per second: sent 8221.2, received 8295.3
    debug1: Exit status -1
```

Answer (score 1):

- Delete and regenerate your RSA keys if possible. Or better yet, restore them from the secure, offsite backup that you undoubtedly took!
- Check /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts/deny to make sure that sshd is allowed to be accessed like you think it should be.
- This could be a result of line wrapping in your key file. Make sure that if you upload a remote key file you read up on ssh-copy-id.